# Is it a good approach to process data via PySpark directly from DWH?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two DWH and I need to process their data via PySpark, jobs will be executed on AWS EMR. I want to understand is it okay to process data via PySpark directly from DWH or it would be better to make ETL from DWH to S3 and then run Spark jobs that will use S3 data.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is slow. Often the ephemeral storage on EMR is used (local + HDFS). But S3 is possible.

In any event you will often need to compare data from DWH with data on HDFS (new mutations) or S3 with EMR. E.g. type 2 dimensions with sd & ed.

I do it differently, i.e. data lake on S3 or HDFS, then the DWH gets processed on that platform. I guess this means for you process locally on that dwh, but then why use EMR?

Comment: Let me explain my situation:
I have data in MS SQL DWH, I need to process this data on EMR cluster via PySpark and store results in the Redshift
For now I want to understand do I need to extract data from DWH to S3 and then process it from S3 or I can connect directly on EMR to DWH make calculations and then store this data in Redhift.
Could you please help me with defining flow how I should move data

Comment: 1. Spark to read your Redshift data to S3 or better local HDFS attached to your EMR Cluster. 3a. Process with Spark on S3 or 3b. Process with Spark on local HDFS and distcopy to S3 if large. 4. COPY from indeed S3 to Redshift, do not use Spark ideally.